# Documentum For Dummies

Tags: content-management-system, documentum6.5

I'm going to work in a project which has Documentum as Content Management system. 
There are some customization on default documentum features such as Task Space.

I'm pretty much new to Documentum, and would like to get high level idea of it.

Any recommendations, for starting off to learn Documentum in High level ?
Any resources,blogs contents, or videos for training on Documentum ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can search the web for "EMC Documentum Content Server Fundamentals Guide" and then if customization needed at coding level you should read "Documentum Foundation Classes"